# How to keep track of a value after I update the component in react 16.3

Tags: reactjs

I just update to the react 16.3. I have a value to keep tracking of a value that I need to post to the server. I want to save `this.value` after some props changed. I found out that a lot of life cycle functions are deprecated. And I cannot save the value into redux before rendered. Could anyone give me a good way to handle it? Thanks.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.value = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //some other components
      <Bar onChange={value => this.value = value} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why can't you just have onChange save the value to redux right there? And changing value will not cause a render because it's not in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would most likely handle it with this

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //some other components
      <Bar onChange={value => this.setState({text:value})} />
    )
  }
}
```

Keep in mind this is ES7 way to do it. A bit cleaner than doing it in constructor(). If you don't use new syntax just initiate state in constructor as,

```
constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {
   text: ''
 }
}
```

if you would like to get your hands dirty more with handling value that user is giving could also pass onChange value to own function and setState on there. Many prefer it that way.

e.g.

```
handleChange = (text) => {
  // Some amaizing text manipulation
  this.setState({text})
}

render() {
  return (
    //some other components
    <Bar onChange={this.handleChange} />
  )
}
```

and with redux dispatch function

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    /**
     * Bind funtions
     */
    const { dispatch } = props
    this.patchReservation = params =>
      dispatch(ActionCreators.patchReservation(params))
  }
```

Then you just attach e.g. `this.patchReservation` to onChange -listener. `ActionCreators` is one of my import's which contains my Redux action -functions.

Cheers!